# Animate 3D plotting data using Mayavi in Python

Tags: python, animation, 3d, geometry, mayavi

I have an array of points (x,y,z) that I would like to animate in 3D using Mayavi (Python). I am currently using a Plot3D command to plot all of the points simultaneously (modeling the movement of a particle), but would love some help on the animation.

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287185/animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot

Comment: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mlab_visual.html
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib offers a lot of possibilities for animation. Have a look at the [specific routines for animation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/index.html). In particular, there's [a specific example for 3D plotting](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html).

There are quite a few tutorials on the 'web. Eg. [Matplotlib Animation Tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) and [Animated 3-D Plots in Python](http://geoffboeing.com/2015/04/animated-3d-plots-python/)

Comment: Thank you! Still trying to use Mayavi if possible, but this is extremely helpful.

Comment: the question was about mayavi,  matplotlib despite ease of use, has some limitations in 3d https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html