# Python - Visualize Dynamic Changes in Graph with Mayavi

Tags: python, visualization, mayavi

I am trying to visualize a 3D graph using Mayavi.

During the program run, some nodes or edges in the graph become unavailable and I want to visualize dynamically that they become inaccessible in the visualization scene. How can I achieve this?

I'm still a newbie in python but it seems that the Mayavi scene can't be changed through the program once it is displayed.

Comment: Please, post more details, share your code. Is there any erros?

Answer (score 1):

It can be changed in many ways. You can add and remove elements, change background and foreground colors, and animate stuff. For example (from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287185/animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot)):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import math

alpha = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 100)  

xs = np.cos(alpha)
ys = np.sin(alpha)
zs = np.zeros_like(xs)

mlab.points3d(0,0,0)
plt = mlab.points3d(xs[:1], ys[:1], zs[:1])

@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def anim():
    f = mlab.gcf()
    while True:
        for (x, y, z) in zip(xs, ys, zs):
            print('Updating scene...')
            plt.mlab_source.set(x=x, y=y, z=z)
            yield

anim()
mlab.show()
```

, will return you an animation where two sphere exist and one is having it's position changed every step of time:

[image: Mayavi animation of sphere location]

The Mayavi documentation isn't exactly brilliant from my point of view but you can get some information both from the examples and chapters. For example [remove an object from Mayavi pipeline](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/advanced_scripting.html#life-cycle-of-the-different-objects).