# Update mayavi plot in loop

Tags: python, interactive, mayavi

What I want to do is to update a mayavi plot in a loop. I want the updating of the plot to be done at a time specified by me (unlike, e.g., the animation decorator).

So an example piece of code I would like to get running is:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

V = np.random.randn(20, 20, 20)
s = mlab.contour3d(V, contours=[0])

for i in range(5):

    time.sleep(1) # Here I'll be computing a new V

    V = np.random.randn(20, 20, 20)

    # Update the plot with the new information
    s.mlab_source.set(scalars=V)
```

However, this doesn't display a figure. If I include `mlab.show()` in the loop, then this steals the focus and doesn't allow the code to continue.

I feel what I should be using is a *traits* figure (e.g. [this](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/building_applications.html)). I can follow the example traits application to run a figure which live-updates as I update the sliders. However, I can't get it to update when my code asks it to update; the focus now is 'stolen' by `visualization.configure_traits()`.

Any pointers, or a link to appropriate documentation, would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

David Winchester's answer gets a step closer to the solution.

However, as I point out in the comments, I am not able to manipulate the figure with the mouse during the `time.sleep()` step. It is during this step that, in the full program, the computer will be busy computing the new value of V. During this time I would like to be able to manipulate the figure, rotating it with the mouse etc.

Comment: In my latest comment you can simplify the code and manipulate the figure during the update without the `time.sleep()`. Did that work for you? The solution should be better than using `wx` since Mayavi is being ported to `qt` :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `wx` backend, you can call `wx.Yield()` periodically if you want to interact with your data during some long-running function. In the following example, `wx.Yield()` is called for every iteration of some "long running" function, `animate_sleep`. In this case, you could start the program with `$ ipython --gui=wx <program_name.py>`

```
import time
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
import wx

V = np.random.randn(20, 20, 20)
f = mlab.figure()
s = mlab.contour3d(V, contours=[0])

def animate_sleep(x):
    n_steps = int(x / 0.01)
    for i in range(n_steps):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        wx.Yield()

for i in range(5):

    animate_sleep(1)

    V = np.random.randn(20, 20, 20)

    # Update the plot with the new information
    s.mlab_source.set(scalars=V)
```

Answer (score 5):

I thin Mayavi uses `generators` to animate data. This is working for me:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

f = mlab.figure()
V = np.random.randn(20, 20, 20)
s = mlab.contour3d(V, contours=[0])

@mlab.animate(delay=10)
def anim():
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        time.sleep(1)
        s.mlab_source.set(scalars=np.random.randn(20, 20, 20))
        i += 1
        yield

anim()
```

I used this post as reference ( [Animating a mayavi points3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287185/animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot) )

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I want. I find though that during the `sleep` step I am not able to manipulate the figure. Do you also have this problem? And any solutions?

Comment: You actually don't need the sleep since the delay is given in the decorator I think. Where exactly are you trying to manipulate the figure?

Comment: By 'manipulate' I mean rotate the image with the mouse. The sleep step is designed to simulate my program doing some processing on the data. The idea is that I want the visualiser to show data during the execution of a slow program, which may only generate new results every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: If you comment the `time.sleep(1)` line and change the decorator to `@mlab.animate(delay=1000, ui=False)` , I get the animation and I can actually manipulate the image while it is being updated. Is this what you needed?

Comment: This answer doesn't really address how to update at a time chosen programmatically/by the user (e.g. randomly), rather than at regular time intervals specified by mlab.animate. An alternative seems to be using traits (there are several examples with sliders), but it seems overly complicated to use traits to request a simple update of a plot.