# How to update a mayavi plot at arbitrary times

Tags: mayavi.mlab

To update plots dynamically, Mayavi uses either generators via `mlab.animate()` as in [this example from the docs](https://mayavi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto/example_mlab_visual.html#example-mlab-visual) or via rather complicated `traits` as in [this other example from the docs](https://mayavi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto/example_mlab_interactive_dialog.html#example-mlab-interactive-dialog).

The solution provided by `mlab.animate()` is simple and neat, but it steals control from the user: updates occurs at regular time intervals. I would like to retain control of the workflow by calling an 'update plot' method within my own loop or after a certain condition of my own is met (without embedding these loops or if conditions within the function called by animate...)

Is there a simple solution that avoids defining classes deriving from `HasTraits` etc.?

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840638/update-mayavi-plot-in-loop) but the accepted answer no longer works with new versions of mayavi.

I would even be interested in a solution with traits, which would update a plot when a `traits.api` parameter is changed programmatically (rather than via the dialog).