# how to animate imshow by mayavi

Tags: python, animation, mayavi, imshow

I am trying to animate imshow() (i.e., change image over time) with mayavi, following the method to animate points3d ([Animating a mayavi points3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287185/animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot)), but the scene never updates.  The following code continues showing the same (initial) image, which I set to zeros.

Your help very much appreciated!

note: I know how to do this in matploblib ([matplotlib imshow(): how to animate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212722/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-animate)). I want to do it now in mayavi.

My environment is:
Ubuntu 16.04
python 2.7.12 / ipython 4.2.0 (both failed)

```
    import numpy as np
    from mayavi import mlab

    @mlab.animate(delay=10)
    def main():
        s = np.zeros((2,2))
        im = mlab.imshow(s, colormap='gist_earth')
        for i in range(100):
            print i
            s += np.random.random((2,2))
            im.mlab_source.set(scalars=s)
            yield

    main()
    mlab.show()
```

Comment: The code is working on my Windows 8, python 2.7, mayavi 4.3.1, VTK 5.10.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. It seems that the key is to find the name of the argument to specify in mlab_source.set() API. I tried both "s" and "scalars" but neither works.