# Python Updating Mayavi Using a Timer While Running Other Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, mayavi

Is it possible to create a Mayavi visualization that is updated on a timed bases rather than through Trait events?

I have a visualization that I need to update continually, but the data I am updating is coming from an external source (I.E. not an event from a user input from the graphical interface).

In the mean time, I need to be running a separate thread - so the Mayavi visualization can't control the main loop.

Can this be done? And if so How??

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Some dummy code for how I'm trying to tackle this is below:

```
import numpy

from mayavi.sources.array_source import ArraySource

from pyface.api import GUI
from mayavi.modules.api import Surface
from mayavi.api import Engine

import threading
import time


# Class runs a given function on a given thread at a given scan time
class TimedThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread, scan_time, funct, *funct_args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        # Thread for the function to operate in
        self.thread = thread

        # Defines the scan time the function is to be run at
        self.scan_time = scan_time

        # Function to be run
        self.run_function = funct

        # Function arguments
        self.funct_args = funct_args

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Locks the relevant thread
            self.thread.acquire()

            # Begins timer for elapsed time calculation
            start_time = time.time()

            # Runs the function that was passed to the thread
            self.run_function(*self.funct_args)

            # Wakes up relevant threads to listen for the thread release
            self.thread.notify_all()

            # Releases thread
            self.thread.release()

            # Calculates the elapsed process time & sleeps for the remainder of the scan time
            end_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            sleep_time = self.scan_time - elapsed_time

            if sleep_time > 0:
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
            else:
                print 'Process time exceeds scan time'


# Function to update the visualisation
def update_visualisation(source):
    print("Updating Visualization...")

    # Pretend the data is being updated externally
    x = numpy.array([0, numpy.random.rand()])
    y = z = x
    data = [x, y, z]
    source.scalar_data = data
    GUI.invoke_later(source.update)


# Function to run the visualisation
def run_main():
    print 'Running Main Controller'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = threading.Condition()

    # Create a new Engine for Mayavi and start it
    engine = Engine()
    engine.start()

    # Create a new Scene
    engine.new_scene()

    # Create the data
    x = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 2)
    y = z = x
    data = [x, y, z]

    # Create a new Source, map the data to the source and add it to the Engine
    src = ArraySource()
    src.scalar_data = data
    engine.add_source(src)

    # Create a Module
    surf = Surface()

    # Add the Module to the Engine
    engine.add_module(surf)

    # Create timed thread classes
    visualisation_thread = TimedThread(c, 2.0, update_visualisation, src)
    main_thread = TimedThread(c, 1.0, run_main)

    # Start & join the threads
    main_thread.start()
    visualisation_thread.start()
    main_thread.join()
    visualisation_thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in the following link:
[Animating a mayavi points3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287185/animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot)

Solved by using the @mlab.animator to call the update function and using the yield command to release the animation to allow for user manipulation.

Solution below:

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.api import Engine

# Class runs a given function on a given thread at a given scan time
class SafeTimedThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_condition, scan_time, funct, *funct_args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        # Thread condition for the function to operate with
        self.tc = thread_condition

        # Defines the scan time the function is to be run at
        self.scan_time = scan_time

        # Function to be run
        self.run_function = funct

        # Function arguments
        self.funct_args = funct_args

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Locks the relevant thread
            self.tc.acquire()

            # Begins timer for elapsed time calculation
            start_time = time.time()

            # Runs the function that was passed to the thread
            self.run_function(*self.funct_args)

            # Wakes up relevant threads to listen for the thread release
            self.tc.notify_all()

            # Releases thread
            self.tc.release()

            # Calculates the elapsed process time & sleep for the remainder of the scan time
            end_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            sleep_time = self.scan_time - elapsed_time

            if sleep_time > 0:
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
            else:
                print 'Process time exceeds scan time'


# Function to run the main controller
def run_main():
    print 'Running Main Controller'


def init_vis():
    # Creates a new Engine, starts it and creates a new scene
    engine = Engine()
    engine.start()
    engine.new_scene()

    # Initialise Plot
    data = np.random.random((3, 2))
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    z = data[2]

    drawing = mlab.plot3d(x, y, z, np.ones_like(x))

    return drawing


@mlab.animate(delay=500, ui=False)
def update_visualisation(drawing):
    while True:
        print ('Updating Visualisation')
        # Pretend to receive data from external source
        data = np.random.random((3, 2))
        x = data[0]
        y = data[1]
        z = data[2]

        drawing.mlab_source.set(x=x, y=y, z=z)
        yield


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create Condition for Safe Threading
    c = threading.Condition()

    # Create display window
    dwg = init_vis()

    # Create safe timed thread for main thread and start
    main_thread = SafeTimedThread(c, 1.0, run_main).start()

    # Update using mlab animator
    vis_thread = update_visualisation(dwg)

    mlab.show()
```